# JDBI testing custom annotation to generate sql statement

Tags: java, jdbi

I am looking to test a custom SqlStatementCustomizingAnnotation annotation within the jdbi package.

http://jdbi.org/#_statement_customizing_annotations

I have the following unit test but I see that the "customizer" object that is returned is a lambda. How to I assert that the SQL I wanted to generate in the custom annotation is what I expect. How do I transform the "customizer" object to a sql statement or inspect and assert the sql in the "customizer" object.

**SourceEventTimeCustomizerTest**

```
 @Test
 public void testSourceModifiedQuery(){
        SourceModifiedQuery.SourceEventDateTimeCustomizer srcModifiedQuery = new SourceModifiedQuery.SourceEventDateTimeCustomizer();

        Annotation annotation = buildSourceModifiedQueryAnnotation();

        List<Query> queries = new ArrayList<Query>();
        queries.add(QueryHelper.createQuery("source_modified_date_time" , Query.Operator.EQ, "2018-01-01"));

        SqlStatementCustomizer customizer = srcModifiedQuery.createForParameter(annotation, DealDao.class, null, queries );
        assertNotNull(customizer);

    }
```

**SourceEventTimeCustomizer**

```
  @Override
        public SqlStatementCustomizer createForParameter(final Annotation annotation, final Class sqlObjectType,
                final Method method, final Object arg) {
            final List<Query> queries = (List<Query>) arg;
            final SourceModifiedQuery sourceModifiedQuery = (SourceModifiedQuery) annotation;

            final String actualQuery = genQuery(queries, sourceModifiedQuery);
            return sqlStatement -> sqlStatement.define(sourceModifiedQuery.value(), actualQuery);
        }
```